# Is data from AWS RDS stored on Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

Does the AWS store all data that are on RDS in Amazon S3? I need to have the same data that is located in RDS on Amazon S3 with all modifications and so on.

Comment: Amazon RDS runs standard database engines, such as PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle. These database engines use disk storage provided by Amazon EBS. What do you mean by "I need to have the same data that is located in RDS on Amazon S3 with all modifications and so on"? What is the use-case for this need? What do you mean by "all modifications and so on"? Please Edit your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export RDS data to S3. See:

- [Exporting DB snapshot data to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html)
- [Exporting data from an RDS for PostgreSQL DB instance to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html)

Comment: So I can just make a snapshot of the DB, AWS doesn't store all data on S3 under the hood?

Comment: RDS is a managed database service. While it might internally store snapshots on an object storage service like S3, it won't expose that to you directly. It certainly won't use S3 for the actual primary RDS storage layer, of course, for performance reasons.